# Pagination in Bar chart using ChartJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bar-chart, chart.js

I am using chartJS for display some data with Bar Chart. there are some issues with chartJs. When i have to much data-filed for example 100 or more data-field and it have long lasting label its looks like ugly.

**how to config bar chart ?**

here is my bar chart screenshot
[image]

here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/KDM1010/7c6zvhu4/)

in above example i have 100 data-filed, can i paginate this bar-chart ?

here is my code

```
var lbl = [];
var dt = [];
for(var i = 1;i<=100;i++){
 lbl.push("this_is_my_lable_name_"+i);
}
for(var i = 1;i<=100;i++){
  dt.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
}
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: lbl,
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: dt,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there a pagination capability built into chart.js.  However, there is a plugin called `chartjs-plugin-zoom` that could work for you, but you will need to extend it to make some changes.  Checkout this [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/VpOrrd) for an example.  You can use your mousewheel to scroll into the chart and then click and drag to pan left/right.  Currently there is no way to pre-set the initial zoom, but you could extend the plugin to add that feature (shouldn't be too difficult).  If this works for your needs then let me know and I'll submit as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this solution to consider the chart scroll like this:

Clone a different canvas for y axis so that when you scroll then only bars will appear to move

Adding the canvas for y axis

```
 <canvas id="myChartAxis" height="600" width="0"></canvas>
```

Now cloning the axis

```
 var sourceCanvas = myLiveChart.chart.canvas;
 var copyWidth = myLiveChart.scales['y-axis-0'].width - 10;
 var copyHeight = myLiveChart.scales['y-axis-0'].height + myLiveChart.scales['y-axis-0'].top + 10;
 var targetCtx = document.getElementById("myChartAxis").getContext("2d");
 targetCtx.canvas.width = copyWidth;
 targetCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight, 0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight);
```

For a Demo see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9oLs4djm/1/)

For better visualization its better to avoid labels in x axis and show this info intuitive via tool tip anyhow

Comment: Thanks @vinod.. :) Thats i want.. You are legend.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the `canvas` with a wrapper class and change its width accordingly which suites you the best. also, if you don't want the chart to cover entire screen, you can wrap it with another wrapper class.

```js
var lbl = [];
var dt = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    lbl.push("this_is_my_lable_name_" + i);
}
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    dt.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
}
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: lbl,
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: dt,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.chartWrapper {
  width: 6000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="chartWrapper">
        <canvas id="myChart" height="19"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

<sub>**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09f8mou9/)**</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, In your solution you are applying X scrollbar for entire canvas, I just want to all bars are scrolled not canvas.